# PHP POST not working but GET works

Tags: php, html, forms, post, xampp

I have been struggling with this weird issue for too long now.

I have searched through all the so posts of the same issue and none of the solutions have helped.

I have an HTML form that is using the post method to log a user in.
The form resubmits to the same page and PHP then checks if the submit button has been clicked and will then execute the appropriate code.

The problem is that my $_POST variable is empty, but if I use the GET method it works.

When I `VAR_DUMP ( $_POST )` it returns `array(0) { }` proving that nothing is getting posted. 
Using $_REQUEST does not work either. 
All my form fields have a name attribute.
I am using XAMPP to host the files and I access it through localhost in my browser http://localhost:8080/project/admin.php

I feel like I am missing something really simple but I can't figure it.

Here is my code

### admin.php

```
<?php
$failed = false;

VAR_DUMP ( $_POST );
if (isset($_POST["loginBtn"]))
{
    echo "<br>working";
    loginUser();
}

function loginUser()
{
    include 'dbconfig.php';//makes connection to the database

    $user = $_POST['username'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];

    $pass = hash("sha256", $pass);
    $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=? AND password =?");
    $sql->bind_param("ss", $user, $pass);
    $sql->execute();
    $result = $sql->get_result();

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
        echo "In match";
        session_start();

        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $id_v = $row["userID"];
        }

        $_SESSION['userId'] = $id_v;
        $_SESSION['sessionId'] = session_id();

        header('Location: newPost.php');

    }
    else
    {
        $failed = true;
    }
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Admin</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="resources/images/favicon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head

<body>
<section class="grey-bg">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="title mb-50 center">
                <h2>Admin Login.</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="section-content">
                    <form action="admin.php" method="POST" role="form" id="form_login" name="form_login" >
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="username">Username</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" id="username"
                                   placeholder="Username"
                                   data-required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="password">Password</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" id="password"
                                   placeholder="Password"
                                   data-required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="btn btn-color-out" type="submit" id="loginBtn" name="loginBtn" value="Login">
                        </div>

                        <?php
                            if($failed)
                            {
                                echo "<span id='errorMsg' style='color: red;'>Username and password do not match</span><br/><br/>";
                            }
                        ?>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) rather than `sha`.

Comment: You'll need to add the HTML form, because we need to know what is sent to the PHP file. **Edit: Sorry, I missed the scrollbar**

Comment: @chade_ the page in the php form; "admin.php" is the one that OP posted

Comment: I wasn't able to replicate this issue on my machine and I was able to output $_POST data with your code (minus the sql stuff)

Comment: <form action=""> empty action since you are posting in the same page or <form action="#">

Comment: then look on the developers tool, inspect element goto network tab and see the headers response

Comment: @bdalina Doesn't have to be an empty action or a #. If you are using a `<base>` tag, your method will actually redirect to the index page

Comment: @Script47 thank you this worked? I'm not sure why sha was causing an issue because it wasn't even reaching that section of code.

Comment: @WillParky93 Thank you, I have used this exact code before and like you it worked. That's why I do not understand why it isn't working now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please make sure the "enable_post_data_reading" variable is set to "on" in php.ini. I have tried the same script on MAMP and it's working fine. So, It's your server settings issue.

Comment: Thank you this was the problem!

Answer (score 0):

php and html as same page,
Remove the Form action

```
<form action="admin.php" method="POST" role="form" id="form_login" name="form_login" >
```

to

```
<form action="" method="POST" role="form" id="form_login" name="form_login" >
```

I get the result after submit the form

```
array(3) { ["username"]=> string(8) "vengades" ["password"]=> string(4) "1234" ["loginBtn"]=> string(5) "Login" }
```

Comment: No matter what I put in the action attribute it still does not work, be it leaving it empty or a # or the pages name.